# Netlogo v6.0.1 - updating & saving code requires closing model for changes to work

Tags: netlogo

I am writing several models in Netlogo v6.0.1. Whenever I make a change to a model code and save it, the change will not take effect until the .nlogo file has been closed and reopened.

This is a recreateable error when I am making changes to .nls files, particularly if I've changed something that uses the GIS extension.

I would appreciate any help.

Best,
Todd

Comment: Todd, I had this very problem with the Beta version of NetLogo 6.0, but I've not seen it with v6.0.1.  When you save the mode with changes to the .nls files, are you using `Save All`?  But you shouldn't have to save at all to see your changes take effect when you run the model.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using 'Save All' when I update .nls files. I doubled checked my version, and it is 6.0.1. I've tried reinstalling, but that didn't fix it. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: This sounds like it should be reported at https://github.com/netlogo/netlogo/issues